# Find second instance of a word in a file and rename file

Tags: command-line, scripts, batch-rename

I files which a system generates with a generic file name.
I want to have a script I can run which scans these files for the second instance of the word ProcID (after the word ProcID is a number) and then renames the file with the ProcID number.
Currently I have the following:

```
FILEPATH; awk -F '[:)]' '/ProcID./{printf "mv %s %s.txt\n", FILENAME, $2 | "/bin/sh"; nextfile}' O*.TXT
```

For example, script scans files and finds second instance of `(ProcID:0000014778)` and then it renames the file with this Proc ID number.

The script above finds only the first instance, and therefore files are being renamed before the system has finished outputting to the file.

Comment: Do you need to set the extension, or just the id? Any risk on dupe names to take into account?

Comment: Hi IanG, just curious, but did you notice the answer(s)?

Comment: HI.
I ran the following, but for some reason it only does one file at a time.
FILEPATH; awk -F '[:)]' '/ProcID./{ count++; if(count == 2 ){ printf "mv %s %s.txt\n", FILENAME, $2 | "/bin/sh"; nextfile}}' O*.TXT
Also, I think if it finds duplicate file names, it is deleting them and not renaming.  So we are looking some reports.

Comment: Did you also try the python answer? If you don't want a python solution, please mention. Also, did you see my first comment?

Comment: Hi Jacob.  Thanks, I would like to avoid the Python method if possible.  Also, we only need to set the ID and not the extension.  Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why no python? You asked *I want to have a script*. If one or more languages are excluded, please add it to your question.

Comment: tried the Python method and get: bash: python3: command not found
Also tried changing the first line of the script to #!/usr/bin/env python and then run the script but just the same issue.

Comment: What was the exact command you ran it with? I can't believe you cannot run python3, *if* you run Ubuntu. What is your os?

Comment: Both Python 2 and Python 3 are widely used today, including for system administration, so you might want to install Python 3. It shouldn't interfere with your Python 2 installation (if any) at all. I think every Ubuntu system has at least one of `python-minimal` or `python3-minimal` preinstalled, though I'm unsure if this is *universally* true on [Ubuntu Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core). Either way, you should be able to get a fully functional Python 3 installation by installing the `python3` package, for example by running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install python3`.

Comment: Found we have Python 2 and 2.4, so run against 2.4, but go this.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILEPATH/rename_files.py", line 13, in ?
    except (IndexError, IsADirectoryError):
NameError: name 'IsADirectoryError' is not defined

Comment: Hi IanG see updated answer (EDIT section)

Comment: @IanG Python 2.4 is ***ancient*** (2003-2006) and is indicative that you're on an ancient (and long-unsupported) version of Ubuntu, or something else entirely, similarly crusty. For things to be answerable by our users —and useful to future users— we require you're using a supported version of Ubuntu and all the shiny things that come with it. We occasionally look the other way, but if you really are on something *that* old, a base prerequisite to any answer you get is going to be upgrading.

Answer (score 5):

The script below renames all files in a directory, to the *id* in the second found string, starting with `ProcID:`:

#### 1. Renaming to the id in the second matching string (literally; no extension)

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    file = os.path.join(dr, f)
    try:
        # only rename if the second instance exists
        new = [s for s in open(file).read().split() if s.startswith("(ProcID:")][1]
    except (IndexError, IsADirectoryError):
        pass
    else:
        # rename the file
        shutil.move(file, os.path.join(dr, new.split(":")[-1].strip()[:-1]))
```

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `rename_files.py`
2. run it with the directory as argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rename_files.py /path/to/directory_with_files
   ```

#### Notes

- The script assumes the (exact) format: `ProcID:0000014778`
- The script will *not* rename files if there is no second instance of `ProcID` (or none at all)

#### 2. Only rename .txt files, and keep the extension

...Then use the version below, it will only rename `.txt` files and keep the extension in the renamed file. Usage is exactly the same.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    file = os.path.join(dr, f)
    try:
        # only rename is the second instance exists
        new = [s for s in open(file).read().split() if all([
            s.startswith("(ProcID:"), f.endswith(".txt")
            ])][1]
    except (IndexError, IsADirectoryError):
        pass
    else:
        shutil.move(file, os.path.join(dr, new.split(":")[-1].strip()[:-1]+".txt"))
```

#### What the script does

- it lists the files in the directory:

  ```
  for f in os.listdir(dr)
  ```
- lists the strings inside the file, starting with `ProcID:`

  ```
  new = [s for s in open(file).read().split() if s.startswith("(ProcID:")][1]
  ```

  The ending `[1]` extracts the second occurrence of strings, starting with `ProcID:` (`[0]` is the first one)
- splits of the id:

  ```
  new.split(":")[-1].strip()
  ```
- and renames the file, using the id:

  ```
  shutil.move(file, os.path.join(dr, new.split(":")[-1].strip()[:-1]))
  ```

---

#### EDIT

Python2 version of script 1. OP turns out to have python2 installed, which requires `IOError` instead of `IsADirectoryError` to prevent errors in case the script runs into a directory instead of a file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    file = os.path.join(dr, f)
    try:
        # only rename if the second instance exists
        new = [s for s in open(file).read().split() if s.startswith("(ProcID:")][1]
    except (IndexError, IOError):
        pass
    else:
        # rename the file
        shutil.move(file, os.path.join(dr, new.split(":")[-1].strip()[:-1]))
```

...and for being complete, a python2 version of the second script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    file = os.path.join(dr, f)
    try:
        # only rename is the second instance exists
        new = [s for s in open(file).read().split() if all([
            s.startswith("(ProcID:"), f.endswith(".txt")
            ])][1]
    except (IndexError, IOError):
        pass
    else:
        shutil.move(file, os.path.join(dr, new.split(":")[-1].strip()+".txt"))
```

Comment: Ran:
python2 /PATH/rename_files.py /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY_WITH_FILES
seems to run, but no change to the file names.

Comment: Then could you give me the content of one of the files (just the relevant strings)? There must be an issue with that, else the files are renamed for sure.

Comment: Here is an example:
UCXJLI3M   Version 6.00A  patchlevel 907-602
JOB 42349166 (ProcID:0000027096) START AT 30.01.2017 /
10:00:02 **
UTC TIME 30.01.2017 / 10:00:02
TEXT="        Job started

0042346870
PROCESSNAME
JOBNAME
/PATH/TO/JOB
*********************************************************************
****           UCXJLI3M   Version 6.00A  patchlevel 907-602      ****
** JOB 42349166 (ProcID:0000014778) ENDED AT 30.01.2017 / 10:00:03 **
**                                  UTC TIME 30.01.2017 / 10:00:03 **
** TEXT="        Job ended               "  RETCODE=00             **

Comment: Yep, got it, will edit. Done, please try again. Wait, still need to edit out `)`. Not sure if I'll make it... need to teach in a minute.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PATH/rename_files.py", line 12, in ?
    new = [s for s in open(file).read().split() if all([
NameError: name 'all' is not defined

Comment: Hi @IanG, I tested on 2.7, which is the earliest I can test for you. I am pretty sure you are not running Ubuntu. Please install a more recent version of python (python3?), since this is impossible to deal with from an Ubuntu machine with 2.7/3.4.

Answer (score 2):

Your original script was kind of close, and it can be edited to count the instances via `if` statement and a counter variable:

```
FILEPATH; awk -F '[:)]' '/ProcID./{ count++; if(count == 2 ){ printf "mv %s %s.txt\n", FILENAME, $2 | "/bin/sh"; nextfile}}' O*.TXT
```

In case you're seeking alternative solution, you could use this Perl 
script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cnt=0;
open(my $fh,'<',$ARGV[0]) or die "open failed";
my $new_name;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ){
    $cnt+=1 if $line =~ /ProcID/;
    if($cnt==2){
        chomp $line;
        my @words = split(/[:)]/,$line); 
        $new_name = $words[1] . ".TXT";
        last;
    }
}
if (defined $new_name){
   rename $ARGV[0], $new_name;
}
close($fh)
```

Sample run:

```
$ ls
0000014777.TXT  rename_by_procid.pl*

$ ./rename_by_procid.pl 0000014777.TXT                                                                                                

$ ls
0000014778.TXT  rename_by_procid.pl*
```

Comment: HI.  Thanks for this.  I tried the following, which does work, but only does one file in a directory, it does not search all files and change.
FILEPATH; awk -F '[:)]' '/ProcID./{ count++; if(count == 2 ){ printf "mv %s %s.txt\n", FILENAME, $2 | "/bin/sh"; nextfile}}' O*.TXT